# Creating ApiKey and SecretKey for Mobile App

Tags: java, c#, android, asp.net-mvc, api

I'm trying to create an API for our project so we can use it in our Android App.here's the scenario:

- User opens the App
- He/She enters Username(phone or email) and Password
- the App sends it to server to verify the account
- if it's verified, then the apps call other APIs to show product and
  etc to user

The thing is that both username and password must be hashed, right?
So if i want to hash them i need a Key (Secret Key) that both App and Server knows so that they can communicate and here's my solution (i need help with the solution as i think it may be a little bit wrong)

- the app reads Unique Device Id, which google calls it "instance ID",
  so i call it instance ID from now on. (reference:
  https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids#instance-ids-guids
  )
- the app sends the "instance ID" to the server
- server creates a new Api Key and Secret Key for that instance ID and
  hash them with that instance ID and send it back to the app
- now everytime user sends a data or request (which can be their login
  information or just a request to an api) i hash the request with
  Secret Key and sends the Api Key in the HTTP Authorization header.
- when the request data is received by server, it reads the Api Key from
  HTTP Authorization header, finds the Secret Key associated with that
  Api Key and use the Secret Key to read the data that is passed to the
  server.

I've never done a thing like this that's why i'm confused.One of the benefits of this is that i can show a list of installed apps for the user an he/she can disable that app so it won't be able to login.

Is my solution safe and is it secure?
I know it's not a coding problem, it's a solution/algorithm problem.But as i mentioned, I've never done a thing like this.If my solution is wrong, i would really appreciate it if you point me into the right direction.

Comment: No, you don't hash client-side. Authentication is a solved problem, I urge you to look into auth services, like [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) perhaps.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to hash the username and password at the app ? hashing is meant to protect the password at the server side. since you are passing username and password only the first time the user logs in  and from there on you use token or api upon successful authentication by the server . you don't need to worry about hashing the password at the client side. this will complicate things since the server has to know the hashing key of the client all the time.

Comment: @DannyD I suggested hashing the username and password for the first time for security reasons.I don't want the password to be a normal parameter to be sent to server, but i don't know, maybe i'm wrong.